# Finding the limit of $ \lim_{x\to0} \frac {\sqrt[3]{1+x} - 1} {x} $

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, limits

$$ \lim_{x\to0} \frac {\sqrt[3]{1+x} - 1} {x} $$

I think I'm missing out on something. Is there a concept to factor $\sqrt[3] {1+x}$?

Thanks.

Comment: Is the numerator supposed to be $\sqrt[3]{1+x}-1$?

Comment: yes, pardon my mistake. I have edited. @Arthur

Comment: No, but there is the formula $a-b=\dfrac{a^3-b^3}{a^2+ab+b^2}$.

Comment: See also: [Using conjugates to find a limit with a cubic root: $\lim_{h\to 0}\frac{\sqrt[3]{h+1}-1}{h}$](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/153578) and [Find the following limit $\lim_{x\to 0}\frac{\sqrt[3]{1+x}-1}{x}$](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/201470)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Setting $$t=\sqrt[3]{1+x}$$ then your term is equivalent to $$\frac{t-1}{t^3-1}$$ and then use that $$t^3-1=(t-1)(t^2+t+1)$$
you get $$\frac{t-1}{(t-1)(t^2+t+1)}=\frac{1}{t^2+t+1}$$ (for $$t\neq 1$$) and the last term tends to $$\frac{1}{3}$$ for $t$ tends to $1$

Comment: So how to continue from this? Can you solve it a little bit more?

Comment: hi linda, i have inserted some steps.

Comment: Does that mean when x tends to 0 then t tends to 1, right?

Comment: yes indeed, that is exactly what it means

Comment: okay thank  you !

Comment: ok, you are welcome, i wish you a nice evening,Linda

Answer (score 10):

Take $f(x)=\sqrt[3]{1+x}$

Then $f(0)=1$

We have that $f(x)$ is differentiable at zero because $x+1$ is differentiable at $0$ with derivative $1$ and $\sqrt[3]{x}$ is differentiable at $1$ thus:

> $$\lim_{x \to 0}\frac{\sqrt[3]{1+x} -1}{x}=\lim_{x \to 0}\frac{f(x)-f(0)}{x-0}=f'(0)$$

Answer (score 4):

Hint: multiply the fraction with $$\frac{\sqrt[3]{1+x}^2+ \sqrt[3]{1+x}+1}{\sqrt[3]{1+x}^2+ \sqrt[3]{1+x}+1}$$

Comment: How did you choose this? I get that $\sqrt[3]{1+x^3}^2$ is to get rid of $\sqrt[3]{1+x^3}$

Comment: @gbox I made a typo in there. Anyways, for any $t$ we have $(t-1)(t^2+t+1)=t^3-1$, and in our case, with $t=\sqrt[3]{1+x}$, the expression $t^3-1$ is a lot nicer. As an added bonus, $t^2+t+1$ doesn't go to $0$ in the limit, and therefore doesn't make the denominator much worse even though it looks bad.

Answer (score 3):

Hint:

multiply numerator and denominator by

$ (\sqrt[3]{(1+x)^2}+\sqrt[3]{1+x}+1)$

Answer (score 2):

This limit is easy to calculate with L'Hôpital's rule:

$$\frac{\frac d{dx}{\sqrt[3]{x+1}-1}}{\frac d{dx}x} = \frac{\frac13(x+1)^{\frac{-2}3}}1 = \frac13.$$

Comment: circular........

Comment: @MathematicsStudent1122 How?

Comment: @Jam Because this limit is exactly what you need to find if you want to derive how to differentiate the cube root. It's the same as $\frac{\sin x}x$.

Comment: @Arthur Ah, I see. I always wondered why everyone was so averse to using l'Hopital's rule. Thanks :)

Comment: @Jam It's a very nice way to find limits, but as you can see you have to be careful in some special cases.